# Notepad++ regex new line before each uppercase character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of data like...

```
OrangeAppleBananaPearGrape
```

I need to get the data to look like....

```
Orange
Apple
Banana
Pear
Grape
```

I am using Notepad++ and have search string (.)([A-Z]) but how can i have a new line at each uppercase letter it finds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the case sensitive box and use a lookahead `(?=...)`:

```
find: (?=[A-Z])
replace: \n
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me in the np++ find and replace:

[image]